# Spring Validator doesn't show error message

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have a problem with my UserValidator class. I'm trying to validate 2 fields of form: username and email and only in case of username the messahe is showing. It's weird for me, because i'm doing it the same way in both cases.

I have **globalmessages.properties** file with my error messages:

```
same.mail=Email exists, type other email!
equal.user=Username exists, type other username!
```

UserValidator class is validated in Controller in that way:

```
@Autowired
private UserValidator userValidator;

@RequestMapping(value = "/adduser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "user") User user, BindingResult result) {
userValidator.validate(user, result);
return "signin";
}
```

In validate method i'm checking if user exists in db and if so error is registered. Then i'm doing the same with email. That's UserValidator's validate method:

```
@Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

        User user = (User) target;

        //check if user exists
        Users users = usersDAOImpl.checkByUsername(user.getUsername());
        //check if email exists
        Emails email = usersDAOImpl.checkByEmail(user.getEmail());

        String emailAddresse = email == null ? "null" : "not null";

        System.out.println("From UserValidator class, before rejecting values- email: "
                + emailAddresse);

        if (users != null)
        {
            errors.rejectValue("username", "equal.user");
            System.out.println("From UserValidator class - user not null: "
                    + users.getUsername());
        }

        if (email != null) 
        {
            errors.reject("email", "same.mail");
            System.out.println("From UserValidator class - email not null: "
                    + email.getEmail());
        }
    }
```

There's my signin form:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form modelAttribute="user" method="get" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/adduser" >
    <table align="left">
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
            <td><font color="red"><form:errors path="username"></form:errors></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><form:input type="password" path="password" /></td>
            <td><font color="red"><form:errors path="password"></form:errors></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Confirm password</td>
            <td><form:input type="password" path="confpassword" /></td>
            <td><font color="red"><form:errors path="confpassword"></form:errors></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>E-mail</td>
            <td><form:input type="email" path="email" /></td>
            <td><font color="red"><form:errors path="email"></form:errors></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Create user"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

When i type existing username and submit the form, the error for username from globalmessages.properties is displaying and when i type existing email, error message isn't displaying, although usersDAOImpl.checkByEmail method works fine and i can see "From UserValidator class - email not null: " + email.getEmail() on console.

Comment: In the controller, check if(bindingResult.hasErrors()), if yes, then you have errors. Also, show your model class, coz validation is based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If e-mail validation should be a field error

The method invocation should be `rejectValue` for the `email` field too. As `reject` sets a *global error* instead of a *field error*.

#### If it really is a global error

Or if you really want a global error, you need to consult the API docs, where you could find out that the signature of `reject` is:

```
void reject(String errorCode, String defaultMessage);
```

so, in your case it would look like this:

```
errors.reject("same.mail", "default message for same email address");
```

This would register a global error with your string in the property file, you just need to create a field in your markup, where the string should appear to the user.

Comment: Thanks very much. I can't believe i have missed that distinction. Now it works well.